# WordML 2003 format to OpenXML format using OpenXML SDK

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

We have a web service which returns WordML as response. I want to convert that WordML to OpenXML using OpenXML SDK. I am new to openXMl so I don't know how to do it.

I have a web service that generates an MS Word document in the WordML format (a single XML file in Word 2003 XML format with a .xml file extension). I would like to automatically convert this into the newer Office Open XML format so that the document could be saved as a .docx file (which in essence is a zip file containing multiple XML files).

The user cannot be assumed to have MS Word installed.

I have been looking for a C# library/code I could use to do this, but couldn't find any that converts .xml 2003 format to .docx

Comment: @JasonPlutext Can you please guide?

Comment: OpenXML cannot open WordML 2003 docs: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b53b7693-be68-4296-85ce-2a02abb0e599/open-xml-sdk-works-for-office-2003?forum=oxmlsdk